# RPM GPG keys for RHEL6 vs older versions

Tags: redhat, rpm, keys

Is something different about the requirements of GPG key formats in RHEL6 that is stopping my standard GPG key being imported? it installs fine on RHEL4 and RHEL5 but not RHEL6, citing the key import failed. I've also noticed that some repos like EPEL have a specific EPEL6 key, suggesting again something is different, but I can't find reference to what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, well it seems that the EL6 specific keys tend to be 4096bit RSA keys. EL4 / EL5 can't seem to verify packages with these keys but will import them. EL6 imports a 4096R key fine, but not at all a 1024 DSA key... seems to be a cut off there.